# add multiple entries on Android App (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, multiple-entries

I have been trying to create my first Android App in which, the users enter many properties of their children, for each child, example :

(name, age, height, weight, gender)

The user can add many entries, and for each child, when he fills the rows and clicks send, the entry goes from his phone (app) to my database.

Can we do this with firebase ? Any help could help me !

Comment: You need to convert all that information into a hashmap and push the hashmap to the database. HashMap<K, V> where k is the key and v is the value

Comment: That use-case sounds quite feasible on top of many technologies, including Android + Firebase. If you're new to Firebase and Android, I recommend taking the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) first.

Comment: @McAlixter have you checked the answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad 
Yes, and I'm gonna try it ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the user enters his information then use `setValue()` to send the data to the database:

```
String name=editText.getText().toString();
int age=Integer.valueOf(editAge.getText().toString());
String gender=editGender.getText().toString();

FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(userId);
ref.child("name").setValue(name);
ref.child("age").setValue(age);
ref.child("gender").setValue(gender);
```

You can retrieve the userid, if you are using firebase authentication. If you did not use it then instead of `child(userId)` write `push()`

After you do the following you will have this database:

```
user
 userId
   name: your_name
   age: your_age
   gender: your_gender
```